# BeautifulSoup find_all() returns nothing []

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape [this page](https://www.sbicard.com/en/personal/offers.page#all-offers) of all the offers, and want to iterate over `<p class="white-strip">` but `page_soup.find_all("p", "white-strip")` returns an empty list [].

My code so far-

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.sbicard.com/en/personal/offers.page#all-offers'

# Opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "lxml")
```

**Edit:** I got it working using Selenium and below is the code I used. However, I am not able to figure out the other method through which the same can be done.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.sbicard.com/en/personal/offers.page#all-offers')

# html parsing
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

# grabs each offer
containers = page_soup.find_all("p", {'class':"white-strip"})

filename = "offers.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

header = "offer-list\n"

f.write(header)

for container in containers:
    offer = container.span.text
    f.write(offer + "\n")

f.close()
driver.close()
```

Comment: View that page's source using your web browser and you'll see that there are no `<p class="white-strip">` tags there. They are dynamically generated using Javascript, by your web browser. Use a different tool such as `selenium`, or scrape the actual data source (an Ajax call, a Javascript variable such as `offerData` etc).

Comment: +selcuk I'm running the inspector on Chrome, and the p tag is inside an unordered list which is under a div. How do you figure out that it is dynamically generated?

Comment: The inspector will show you the final DOM, not the actual HTML you downloaded from the server. Use "Right Click > View Source" to see the downloaded HTML.

Comment: I see, so is it a good practice to view the page source as you mentioned, or how do we go about it? How do I find the Javascript variable or that specific ajax call? Also, is using the Selenium method more efficient?

Comment: In general using the source (as in @SIM's method) whenever possible is always more efficient but since Selenium uses a real web browser it is a more general purpose (although inefficient if you are scraping a large number of URLs at once) solution.

Comment: I see your point +Selcuk. However I am not able to understand his method. Could you explain a bit on that, or point me in the right direction? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look for either of the items, you can find them within a script tag containing `var offerData`. To get the desired content out of that script, you can try the following.

```
import re
import json
import requests

url = "https://www.sbicard.com/en/personal/offers.page#all-offers"

res = requests.get(url)
p = re.compile(r"var offerData=(.*?);",re.DOTALL)
script = p.findall(res.text)[0].strip()
items = json.loads(script)
for item in items['offers']['offer']:
    print(item['text'])
```

Output are like:

```
Upto Rs 8000 off on flights at Yatra
Electricity Bill payment – Phonepe Offer
25% off on online food ordering
Get 5% cashback at Best Price stores
Get 5% cashback
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I understood the selenium method, but am having trouble understanding your solution. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: +SIM I would really appreciate some explanation about your code. Seems like it is the way to go but I am stranded.

Comment: Thank you but you elaborated on the wrong part. How do I know that it's json? I'm sorry I'm dealing with this the first time in my life.

Comment: The portion I described above is mostly the unknown part to most of the people. Check out this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp) to understand how json syntax looks like. Keep pressing the next button located at the bottom right until you fully understand about json. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[website](https://www.sbicard.com/en/personal/offers.page#all-offers) is dynamic rendering request data.
You should try automation selenium library. it allows you to **scrape** dynamic rendering request(js or ajax) page data.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver")
driver.get('https://www.sbicard.com/en/personal/offers.page#all-offers')

page_soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
p_list = page_soup.find_all("p", {'class':"white-strip"})

print(p_list)
```

where `'/usr/bin/chromedriver'` selenium web driver path.

**Download selenium web driver for chrome browser:**

http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

**Install web driver for chrome browser:**

https://christopher.su/2015/selenium-chromedriver-ubuntu/

**Selenium tutorial:**

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: `DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver=webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver")` I think it's more than a warning, I get an error related to this straight after